# How to upgrade File::Path on my Mac OS X as a non-root user

Tags: osx, perl, cpan

My mac machine is quite old (Mac OS X 10.6.8) and I have a question on how to upgrade a perl module `File::Path`.

I mostly compile my LaTeX document using [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) which is basically a perl script. It requires `File::Path` version 2.08 but I got an outdated one (version 2.07_02) in my machine. This is the error message I got while running the `latexmk` command.

```
>> latexmk doc.tex
File::Path version 2.08 required--this is only version 2.07_02 at /usr/texbin/latexmk line 129.
```

When I ran `cpan` as a non-root user and tried to upgrade this package by running the command `upgrade File::Path`, I got this message on the screen.

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0/File'
mkdir /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0/File: Permission denied at 
  /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 479   
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
make: *** [pure_perl_install] Error 13
  DLAND/File-Path-2.09.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Failed during this command:
 DLAND/File-Path-2.09.tar.gz                  : install NO
```

Is it possible to upgrade a perl module as a non-root user using `cpan` in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the existing installation as non-root.  But you can install a CPAN module in your home directory (or wherever you have write access) and then load that module preferentially (in most cases.  It is possible for there to be conflicts between modules, but you're probably okay here).

There are instructions for doing this via the `cpan` tool in the perlfaq.  But it can be a bit fiddly.  Using `cpanm` is often recommended.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user has detailed instructions for installing `cpanm`.

Then when installed, you just need to use it instead of the system module.  There are several ways to do so.

You can set PERL5LIB to your local directory.  As an example:

```
$ export PERL5LIB=~/perl5
$ perl myprog
```

If you just need to do this for a small number of scripts, you can add the path in the script itself:

```
#!/bin/perl
use lib '/home/me/perl5';
use File::Path;
```

Either of those should suffice for you, but if you're just testing things, you can also add a location to the path temporarily like this

```
$ perl -I ~/perl5 myprog
```